# JConsole shows 1.8GB heap memory

Tags: jvm, jconsole

Ran a sample program which is stuck for a user input. Opened the same in JConsole and observed that the max heap memory usage shows 1.8GB. Is this right? I've installed 64 bit jvm. What should be the maximum heap size and on what does it depend?

Comment: *"Is this right?"* - Why not? Any problems with that? If you want to limit the heap usage, use `-Xmx` JVM option.

Comment: @apangin Does the heap size vary depending on the program I'm running? What is the default heap size for 64-bit jvm?\

Comment: Depends on JVM version. Oracle JDK 7 and JDK 8 set the default maximum heap size to 1/4 of physical memory.